# how to display .json file contents from an absolute path of client's computer

Tags: json, html

I have come accross the following html5 code which selects the .json from from local file system and displays its contents.
     But I need help in selecting the json file (without file upload dialog) from the pre-defined absolute path "C:\data.json"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>On loaded file + AngularJS</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Select text file</h1>
    <input type="file" on-read-file="showContent($fileContent)" />
    <div ng-if="content">
        <h2>File content is:</h2>
        <pre>{{ content }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showContent = function($fileContent){
        $scope.content = $fileContent;
    };
  });

myapp.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

            element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
//]]>  

</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking effectively is reading a local file *without* the client's explicit permission (having *once* being selected doesn't count), which has been avoided by design as it obviously introduces many kinds of threats. ;-)

It seems impossible to be done in any formal way. If you could explain on your actual goal, we might be able to suggest a different way.

Comment: There is a configuration file on my system(client) which should be used to load parameters into elements(dropdown and labels) during an offline mode. This configuration file is defined only once and ought to be taken implicitly during offline mode.

Comment: I'm sorry about taking years to respond. I think now I understand what you meant.
Would it make sense if you let the client/user select the file or drag-and-drop it into your app, then you'll keep it in browser memory/cache for a longer term?